# MySQL Consultar varios datos de un mismo campo

Tags: mysql

Hola espero explicar bien mi problema, primero disculpas si mi pregunta no se entiende, de una tabla log de eventos requiero obtener datos de esos eventos, tengo los campos FECHA, ID, DATO el campo FECHA es de tipo DATETIME, el campo ID representa el nombre de evento, el campo DATO representa un valor entero.

[image: Tabla]

Como pueden ver en la imagen se tiene una tabla con tres columnas se requiere sacar varios datos del campo ID algo similar a la siguiente imagen.

[image: Resultado de consulta]

para esto estaba pensando usar subconsultas, pero no estoy teniendo mucha suerte.

```
Select (select FECHA, DATO from MI_TABLA where ID=90), (select FECHA, DATO from MI_TABLA where ID=100), (select FECHA, DATO from MI_TABLA where ID=150) where FECHA between '14/11/2017' and '27/11/2017';
```

agradezco su gentil atención.

Comment: *se requiere sacar varios datos del campo ID*... el campo `ID` es un solo dato. Otra cosa es que quieras extrar *algo*  de esos datos. ¿Es eso? ¿Quieres dividir los datos contenidos en el campo `ID`? ¿Qué criterios quieres aplicar para dividirlo o para extraer parte de su información? Sin esa información sería imposible adivinar lo que quieres hacer. ¿O lo que quieres es columnas dinámicas que te cuenten cuantos valores de cada número hay según el dato `ID`?

Comment: Hola, como mencione esta tabla registra eventos de datos lo que se quiere sacar es en base a una fecha los cambios de sus datos de los tres ID, es decir que cambios registraron en su valor cada ID en una determinada fecha, espero haber aclarado la consulta, Saludos.

Comment: Pero a ver, tienes qué explicar qué significan los resultados de tu última imagen, por ejemplo, tomemos la primera fila: ¿de dónde sale el 10, el 0 y el 5 de cada columna? Ese es el punto central de tu pregunta y eso no lo explicas. ¿Ese valor es una suma de todos los valores del campo `DATO`  para cada `ID` `n` en una fecha determinada?

Comment: Ha ok, tenemos las dos imágenes de arriba, la primera imagen es una parte de la tabla de la que deseo obtener datos, la segunda imagen representa los datos que se desean obtener, como pueden ver en la primera imagen el campo ID existen tres diferentes valores 90,100,150 que representan un determinado evento, el campo DATO representa los valores que se registraron para cada ID en un determinado momento, lo que se desea hacer es agrupar en una tabla esos tres ID y obtener los cambios de valor que registraron en el campo DATO en base a un rango de fechas, saludos.

Comment: Para ser más claros, tú pusiste una primera imagen con unas fechas, pero en la segunda imagen pones resultados de fechas que no aparecen en la 1ª imagen y eso dificulta aún más el entendimiento del problema. **¿Podrías indicar qué resultados esperas basados en los datos que se ven en la 1ª imagen?**

Comment: Basado en una fecha extraer cada ID  en una columna diferente, y mostrar los cambios de valor correspondientes a ese campo que en este caso es DATO.

Comment: Hola, ya edite las tablas para que se entienda mejor, espero que con esto sea suficiente, por que ya no se como explicar mi pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es un tipo de PIVOT. Esto lo puedes simular con agregaciones condicionales:

```
select fecha,
       max(case when id = '3678' then dato end) as id_3678,
       max(case when id = '3676' then dato end) as id_3676,
       max(case when id = '3686' then dato end) as id_3686
  from tbl
 group by fecha
 order by fecha
```

Por supuesto, para que esto funcione, se asume que ya sabes de antemano cuales son los valores posibles para la columna `ID`.

Comment: sstan, gracias por la respuesta era justo lo que estaba buscando, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien tu sentencia debería quedar de esta manera:

```
select fecha, dato from MI_TABLA where id in(90,100,150) and fecha between '14/11/2017' and '27/11/2017'
```

Comment: Hola, lo que se requiere es ordenar los datos en varias columnas tal como el ejemplo de la imagen, esto es por que se desea comparar esos datos en esa fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como esto?

```
    SELECT FECHA, max(case when ID=3678 then DATO end) as "3678", max(case when ID=3676 then DATO end) as "3676", max(case when ID=3686 then DATO end) as "3686" from MI_TABLA group by FECHA ASC
```